# What is the convention for the codimension of an empty set?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, krull-dimension

I am learning about dimension and codimension of algebraic sets at the moment. I know that if $V \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ is an algebraic set defined by polynomials $f_1, ..., f_r \in \mathbb{C}[x_1, ..., x_n]$, then the dimension of $V$ equals the Krull dimension of $\mathbb{C}[x_1, ..., x_n] / (f_1, ..., f_r)$.

I was wondering what is the convention for the codimension of an empty set.
Could some one please clarify this for me?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The empty set is not always assigned a co-dimension, but if it has to be done, $\infty$ makes sense. For instance if $X$ and $Y$ intersect nicely you'd expect the codimension of their intersections to add up. Since the intersection of anything with the empty set is the empty set, $\infty$ would work because $\infty + k = \infty$.

See for instance, [these notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/0708-216/216class19.pdf) of Ravi Vakil, where he assigns dimension $-\infty$ to $\emptyset$.

See also [the stacks project](http://[http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0054][2]) where the Krull dimension is unusually defined so as to imply $\dim \emptyset = - \infty$.

Comment: @Fred: Dimension is the intrinsic notion, codimension is secondary and depends on the ambient space. If X is a subspace of Y the codimension of X in Y is dim Y - dim X. Therefore if $X=\emptyset$ and Y has finite dimension d, the codimension of X in Y is d - dim (X) = d - (-$\infty$) = $\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the ring of functions on the empty set is the zero ring, and it's unclear what the Krull dimension of the zero ring should be since it has no prime ideals (it's the only commutative ring with this property), so the supremum you're taking to define the Krull dimension is a supremum over the empty set.

One plausible value to assign this is $-\infty$, as Prometheus says; this is a convention which has various nice properties. For example, defining the dimension of the empty set in this way preserves the property that

$$\dim(X \times Y) = \dim X + \dim Y.$$

Comment: In general, the supremum over no elements of a poset is its smallest element, if that exists. Here the poset is $\mathbb{Z}$ with a smallest element $-\infty$ adjoined.

Comment: @Fred: sure, but of course the dimension and the codimension should sum to the ambient dimension, so the two determine each other. When I say the dimension of the empty set should be $-\infty$ I'm also saying that its codimension in any nonempty variety should be $\infty$.

Comment: @Fred: that doesn't agree with the meaning of codimension that I'm familiar with.

Comment: @Fred: the OP's question is about algebraic sets. In that setting every reasonable notion of dimension and codimension should agree and should be calculable from Zariski tangent spaces. There's no need to entertain strange pathologies here. In any case, if that was the point you actually wanted to make you could've done it in one comment instead of three.